# Python Pandas overlapping data with TimeGrouper

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, pandas

I'm trying to efficiently divide long-term data into 8 intervals for each day. The intervals are 3 hours each, but the edges overlap:

```
00.00 - 03.00
03.00 - 06.00
06.00 - 09.00
09.00 - 12.00
12.00 - 15.00
15.00 - 18.00
18.00 - 21.00
21.00 - 24.00
```

I tried to following:

```
data = data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('4h', closed='left'))
for t, group in groups:
    print(group)
```

The result is:

```
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 00:00:00 -0.2 -2.4
2010-01-01 01:00:00 -0.1 -2.8
2010-01-01 02:00:00  0.8 -2.3
2010-01-01 03:00:00  1.2 -2.0
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 04:00:00  1.2  0.0
2010-01-01 05:00:00  0.8  0.8
2010-01-01 06:00:00  0.3  1.8
2010-01-01 07:00:00 -0.5  2.8
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 08:00:00 -4.6  3.7
2010-01-01 09:00:00 -7.6  1.3
2010-01-01 10:00:00 -8.0 -1.1
2010-01-01 11:00:00 -7.8 -2.4
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 12:00:00 -5.4 -3.0
2010-01-01 13:00:00 -0.3 -0.9
2010-01-01 14:00:00  1.9 -0.3
2010-01-01 15:00:00  2.3  0.1
           ...
```

But what I want instead is:

```
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 00:00:00 -0.2 -2.4
2010-01-01 01:00:00 -0.1 -2.8
2010-01-01 02:00:00  0.8 -2.3
2010-01-01 03:00:00  1.2 -2.0
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 03:00:00  1.2 -2.0
2010-01-01 04:00:00  1.2  0.0
2010-01-01 05:00:00  0.8  0.8
2010-01-01 06:00:00  0.3  1.8
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 06:00:00  0.3  1.8
2010-01-01 07:00:00 -0.5  2.8
2010-01-01 08:00:00 -4.6  3.7
2010-01-01 09:00:00 -7.6  1.3
                       X    Y
2010-01-01 09:00:00 -7.6  1.3
2010-01-01 10:00:00 -8.0 -1.1
2010-01-01 11:00:00 -7.8 -2.4
2010-01-01 12:00:00 -5.4 -3.0
           ...
```

(note the duplicate points at the edges)

Can this be done efficiently with Pandas and/or Numpy? (the dataset is 100 years long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but I think it probably has to be given that you are going to have duplicate timestamps by design (and want them in different groups).  Note that this of course will only work with regularly spaced rows.

First, just use advanced/fancy indexing to duplicate every third row:

```
df2 = df.append(df.iloc[3::3]).sort().reset_index()
```

Then create a simple grouper:

```
df2['grp'] = df2.index.values / 4
```

Check:

```
for i, g in df2.groupby('grp'): print g

         date      time    X    Y  grp
0  2010-01-01  00:00:00 -0.2 -2.4    0
1  2010-01-01  01:00:00 -0.1 -2.8    0
2  2010-01-01  02:00:00  0.8 -2.3    0
3  2010-01-01  03:00:00  1.2 -2.0    0
         date      time    X    Y  grp
4  2010-01-01  03:00:00  1.2 -2.0    1
5  2010-01-01  04:00:00  1.2  0.0    1
6  2010-01-01  05:00:00  0.8  0.8    1
7  2010-01-01  06:00:00  0.3  1.8    1
          date      time    X    Y  grp
8   2010-01-01  06:00:00  0.3  1.8    2
9   2010-01-01  07:00:00 -0.5  2.8    2
10  2010-01-01  08:00:00 -4.6  3.7    2
11  2010-01-01  09:00:00 -7.6  1.3    2
```